# Long vs float speed of large numbers math on python 2.7.x

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I have some large integers of which I know that they are *likely* greater than [`sys.maxint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxint) but **surely** less than `10**16` so they are inside [decimal precision of floats](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.float_info). Now I want to do lots of simple arithmetic operations on them. All operation results are guaranteed to be less than `10**16` as well.

I noticed that converting to `float` and doing operations there is at least 20% faster than operating on them as on `long` (Python 2.7.12 on Windows x64).

Can I rely on this behaviour and switch my calculations from `long` to `float` or does this performance boost depend on the hardware/python implementation? Are there any other ways to improve performance in this case?

I don't care about any decimal points (in case of `a / b` I just throw any remainder off) but the integer part must be exact.

My benchmark

`longtest.py`:

```
n = 10 ** 10
nums = [x for x in xrange(2, 100000)]

def testdiv():    
    for x in nums:
        n/x

def testsum():    
    for x in nums:
        n+x

def testmul():    
    for x in nums:
        n*x

def testsub():    
    for x in nums:
        n-x
```

`floattest.py`:

```
import math
fl = math.floor
n = 1.0 * 10 ** 10
nums = [x * 1.0 for x in xrange(2, 100000)]

def testdiv():    
    for x in nums:
        fl(n/x)

def testsum():    
    for x in nums:
        n+x

def testmul():    
    for x in nums:
        n*x

def testsub():    
    for x in nums:
        n-x
```

Benchmark code `longvsfloat.py`:

```
import timeit

num = 100

print 'float testdiv:', timeit.timeit( 'floattest.testdiv()', setup = 'import floattest', number=num)
print 'long testdiv:', timeit.timeit( 'longtest.testdiv()', setup = 'import longtest', number=num) 

print 'float testsum:', timeit.timeit( 'floattest.testsum()', setup = 'import floattest', number=num)
print 'long testsum:', timeit.timeit( 'longtest.testsum()', setup = 'import longtest', number=num) 

print 'float testmul:', timeit.timeit( 'floattest.testmul()', setup = 'import floattest', number=num)
print 'long testmul:', timeit.timeit( 'longtest.testmul()', setup = 'import longtest', number=num) 

print 'float testsub:', timeit.timeit( 'floattest.testsub()', setup = 'import floattest', number=num)
print 'long testsub:', timeit.timeit( 'longtest.testsub()', setup = 'import longtest', number=num)
```

Results:

```
float testdiv: 1.18729637828
long testdiv: 1.24389351342

float testsum: 0.48933646021
long testsum: 0.880058590455

float testmul: 0.477367560491
long testmul: 1.00981425402

float testsub: 0.48860840934
long testsub: 0.83331387588
```

Comment: `(10**15+1/3-10**15)*3 = 1.125` so avoid floats if you need unit precision and are not sure of what's going on at every intermediate steps...

Comment: As long as you avoid situations like the one Julien shows you should be ok. I get results consistent with your timings, running on Python 2.6.6 on a 32 bit Linux system. I get similar (although mostly faster) results on Python 3.6 (once I convert the `print`s and `xrange`s). BTW, you should use `//` for floor division, either with floats or integers.

Comment: `surely less than 10**16 so they are inside decimal precision of floats`: float have int precision up to `(1 << sys.float_info.mant_dig)` (generally 2**53)